# Why text color overflows to cell border in mozilla?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have made a simple html with table and javascript to format it. But the behaviours were unexpected in firefox and works in chrome. The text color overflows to the cell border

HTML code:

In this html code. I have added table tag with 6 rows and 1 header.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="test.css" />
</head>

<body bgcolor="#0b1b2a">
    
    
        <center><table id="table1" border='1' style="width: 100%;text-align: center;">
            <tr>
                <th>x</th>
                <th>y</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody id="tableContent">
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>not a sample</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>not a sample</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>not a sample</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>not a sample</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>not a sample</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>sample</td>
                    <td>not a sample</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table></center>


</body>



<script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</html>
```

CSS code:

In this css code, I have added some styles to the table and the page. I have also added dark bg to depict the issue.

```
body{
    background-color: #0b1b2a;
}
#table1{
    color: #FFF;
    width: 90%;
    border: solid 2px;
    border-color: #aaa !important;
    border-collapse: collapse ;
    font-weight: 700;
}
tr{
    text-align: center;
    
}
tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #10273c;
    
}
tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #0b1b2a;
    
}
canvas{
    width: 90% !important;
    height: 400px !important;
    
}
```

JS code:

In this Java script code, I have got all td tags and compared their values. if the text is equal to "sample" it will be red in color or else it will be yellow.

```
list_td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
// Getting all td tags

for(elems in list_td){

    // Comparing the inner values and setting text color
    
    if(list_td[elems].innerHTML == "sample"){
        list_td[elems].style.color = "#f00"
    }
    else{
        list_td[elems].style.color = "#ff0"
    }
}
```

Output in Firefox:
[image: Output in firefox]

Output in chrome:
[image: Output in chrome]

Firefox version: 82.0
Chrome version: 86.0.4240.183

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
tr,td{
  border-color: white;
}
```